# Elimination reaction with bad leaving groups

Tags: organic-chemistry

If a halogen is present, as in case of 2-fluorobutane, which is reacted upon by alc. KOH then, shouldn't the product be according to Zaitsev's rule.

Then, why does the removal of hydrogen takes place, does this happens in case of halogens only or in case of all the bad leaving groups?

Comment: Sorry, your question is unreadable. You *can* write perfectly good long sentences in English, but you need to have a flawless grammar to remain legible. In the meantime, split it in two or three, add a fourth.

Answer (score 1):

Alkyl halides with bad-leaving groups (like $\ce{F-}$) having *EWG* at $\ce{\beta}$-position undergoes these reactions, also known as $\ce{E_{1CB}}$, viz. **e**limination **u**nimolecular **c**onjugate **b**ase.

[Example:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/E1cB-elimination_reaction)

- aldol condensation

[image: Aldol]

- photo-induced decarboxylation

[image: Decarboxylation]

Reagent: bulky or strong bases or both (like $\ce{K+(^tBu)-, LDA, NaOH, KNH2}$, etc) along with some heating.

[Mechanism:](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Organic_Chemistry/Map%3A_Organic_Chemistry_(McMurry)/11%3A_Reactions_of_Alkyl_Halides-_Nucleophilic_Substitutions_and_Eliminations/11.11%3A_The_E1_and_E1cB_Reactions)

[image]

Comment: $\ce{OH-}$ leaving is unlikely. It is more like $\ce{H2O}$ leaving after exchange hydrogen from available water molecules.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne: yes, thanks for pointing out. I've added some examples from Wikipedia.